# Excel: Data validation list enable option for all values

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation, list

I am using a data validation list to dictate the outcome of a SUMIF formula.  I'd like the user to be able to select a specific geographical location in the drop down list or to return the sum for all locations.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: I am not sure if I got your point, but assuming that the SUMIF formula is in cell C3 , C4 , C5....you can point the validation list to this range C3:C5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a pull-down in **C1** and data in columns **E** and **F**, in **D1** enter:

```
=IF(C1="All",SUM(F2:F25),SUMIF(E2:E25,C1,F2:F25))
```

[image]

with:

[image]